# React-Navigation v5: How to get screen's state from header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

According to the React-Navigation docs (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/), in the header, we can interact with screen's state:

```
function StackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
          headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} />,
        })}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <Button onPress={() => setCount(c => c + 1)} title="Update count" />    // <===== SET STATE
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  return <Text>Count: {count}</Text>;
}
```

It works fine when I `set` screen's state from header. But when I try to `get` screen's state from header, it's always return the initial value of state.

```
<Button
  onPress={() => {
      setCount(c => c + 1);
      alert(count)
    }}
  title="Update count" />
```

[image: Press button]
[image: Press button again]

How can I get the current state of screen from header?

Comment: setCount, like all useState functions, doesn't execute automatically. There is always a small delay before `count` is updated. You should do a `setTimeout(()=>alert(count), 500);` and it should work

Comment: @QrowSaki : I've tried, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the solution:

Problem is in the `React.useLayoutEffect()` function.
I need to pass `[count]` to the second argument of this function instead of `[navigation]`:

```
React.useLayoutEffect(()=>{
    ...
}, [count]);
```

Then, it works fine